# Which apache/httpd (root or www-data) user, who load /etc/php.ini when webserver startup?

Tags: linux, php, security, httpd, php.ini

I want to secure my php ini access right.

We know that apache/httpd master process, is owned by root. Then it spawn new child process in www-data user.

If /etc/php.ini loaded by apache as root user, I want to limit read access of php.ini to root only.

So,
Which apache/httpd (root or www-data) user, who load /etc/php.ini when webserver startup?

Comment: Couldn't you just change the permissions, restart httpd and see wether it still works or not?
I do not think limiting access to php.ini is a good idea at all, but your use-case might be different.

Answer (score 1):

This permission change can be answered by snips from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5165435/3886428)

> You can determine which user is running PHP by running a simple script that calls the 'whoami' program installed in most Linux:
>
> ```
> <?php
> echo `whoami`;
> ```

This gives you which user the files should have access to. Make sure that the user the PHP process is running under is the owner of php.ini and the *.php files. 
You can change the owner by using this command(replace theuser as per the whoami output):

```
% chown theuser:theuser -R /var/www/website/
```

If you do not have multiple users then permission 600 is fine.

```
% chmod 600  /etc/php.ini
```

And to verify the access use `su - otheruser` from root and try accessing the files.

Comment: Why would you need execute permission on an ini file ?

Comment: I checked and we don't need execute permissions. So 600 would suffice.